# Yii2: How to apply ntext format with html format in a GridView?

Tags: yii2, format

I have the column called **query** and the column called **description** from an index.php file generated with Gii Generator for Yii2. Both belong to the GridView widget.

I want to use the `ntext` format provided by Yii2 for the **query** column because I need the breaks.

[ntext](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asNtext()-detail): formats the value as an HTML-encoded plain text with newlines converted into breaks.

```
'columns' => [
    'description:ntext',
    [
        'attribute' => 'query',
        'format' => 'html',
        'value' => function($model) {
            return "<span style='font-family: Dejavu Sans, monospace'>" . $model->query . '</span>';
        }
    ],
]
```

Here I can't show the breaks:
[image: Query field]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`asNtext()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asNtext()-detail) directly:

```
'columns' => [
    'description:ntext',
    [
        'attribute' => 'query',
        'format' => 'html',
        'value' => function($model) {
            return "<span style='font-family: Dejavu Sans, monospace'>" 
                . Yii::$app->formatter->asNtext($model->query) . '</span>';
        }
    ],
]
```